# File in Chrome Dev tools shows different, older code than what I have now in app. How do I get the correct code to go live?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, nodemon

This is the first time I've ran into this problem.

Making a node.js app in VSStudio code, and using nodemon to watch and run my server. Everything was working great until recently. Now when I start my development server, there is one file that refuses to use the most "current" code. Any ideas how to fix?

[VS Studio Code (The Code I want to be used)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCu0U.png)

- Removed the Promise.then().
- Reworked the response, and the reassigned location.

[Chrome Dev Tools (Code that is actually being used)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kCza.png)

I've updated other files in my app and they have gone "live" just fine. I'm not sure why this file doesn't.

These are my scripts.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch --no-hmr ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js --public-url /js",
    "build:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
```

I tried rebundling my javascript, and restarted my server. I double checked my routers/controllers. I made sure there wasn't a second signup.js file.

Thanks for any help!